# OneToMany ou ManyToOne?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Boa noite, eu tenho algumas dúvidas básicas de iniciante

Eu preciso criar uma linha temporal que tenha o seguinte: Quais eventos ocorreram em determinado intervalo de datas, quem nasceu e que morreu neste intervalo? Eu tenho as classes Pessoa, Evento e Timeline. Minha classe Timeline é a que determina o intervalo de datas, assim um intervalo de dados tem muitos eventos. Com essa lógica eu teria que criar uma uma classe para Nascimentos e outra para Falecimentos ou posso criar uma única para representar isso com um atributo para diferenciar e como seria ela? Como o relacionamento é OneToMany vai ser gerado as tabelas Timeline_Evento, Timeline_Nascimento e Timeline_Falecimento. Se eu fazer ManyToOne a classe Evento terá que ter o atributo intervalo, assim como as classes Nascimento e Falecimento. Qual dessas soluções seria melhor?

Pessoa{
id nome dtNascimento dtFalecimento
}

Evento{
id titulo descricao //timeline?
}

Timeline{
id intervalo Collection(eventos nascimentos falecimentos)
addEvento(evento) addNascimento(nascimento) addFalecimento(falecimento)
}

Nascimento{
id pessoa //timeline?
}

Falecimento{
id pessoa //timeline?
}

//Unica classe com atributo que diferencia
NomeClasse{
id pessoa n/m //timeline?
}

EDIT:

Eu pensei assim: Se um intervalo da classe Timeline tem uma lista de eventos, ela também terá as lista de falecimentos e nascimentos. Assim eu teria que criar essas classes. O problema neste caso é que se o relacionamento for OneToMany vai ser gerado automaticamente mais três tabelas. Se eu fizer ManyToOne as listas não existirão na classe Timeline que passará a ter somente o atributo intervalo e as classes Evento, Nascimento e Falecimento passam a ter um atributo do tipo Timeline. A conclusão que eu cheguei que não importa qual tipo de relacionamento que eu escolha eu vou ter que ter uma ou duas classes para representar Nascimentos e Falecimentos

Exemplo de como deve ficar na view.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria assim:

Teria na mesma tabela o nascimento e o falecimento, e quando quizesse calcular quem nasceu e quem faleceu num determinado intervalo de tempo faria uma query:

```
SELECT (campos que ache necessário mostrar) FROM pessoa 
WHERE dataNascimento BETWEEN 'dataA' AND 'dataB'
OR dataFalecimento BETWEEN 'dataA' AND 'dataB'
```

Espero ter ajudado.